# Types in OCaml Error: The type abbreviation symbol is cyclic

Tags: types, ocaml

```
type symbol = symbol*symbol;;
Error: The type abbreviation symbol is cyclic
```

How can we write this i.e., (1) or (1,2) or (1,2,3) .... will be a type in OCaml?

Comment: The language is spelled “OCaml”. You can find help with the syntax for presenting your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

There really is no usable type like what you ask for. If your values are all ints, what you describe is essentially a list of ints.

Answer (score 0):

The closest type you can define is a variant with just one constructor:

`type symbol = S of (symbol * symbol)`